# Why does bpy.ops.clip.detect_features() not get executed on specific frame?

Tags: python, scripting, tracking, movie-clip-editor

I'm attempting to navigate to a specific frame in the Movie Clip Editor in order to subsequently detect features on the new frame. However, I'm encountering issues with the execution order of my Python code. Initially, I set the desired frame using `bpy.context.scene.frame_current = frame` to move to the specified frame. Following that, I utilize `bpy.context.area.tag_redraw()` to refresh the Movie Clip Editor timeline because, for unknown reasons, the frame does not update properly in that editor. Finally, I employ `bpy.ops.clip.detect_features()` to identify features on the new frame.

The problem arises when executing this code: the updated frame and the newly added tracking points appear simultaneously. Consequently, the tracking points generated by the `bpy.ops.clip.detect_features()` function are based on the original frame, which is not the desired outcome.

I even attempted using `time.sleep()` functions to introduce delays before executing the `bpy.ops.clip.detect_features()` function. However, this approach yielded the same result as before, where the frame updates at the same time as the detection function is called. It appears that the script is not executing in the correct order.

**Here is the simple script:**

```
import math
import time

MiddleFrame = int(NumberOfFrames / 2)
bpy.context.scene.frame_current = MiddleFrame

print("Checkpoint1")
time.sleep(2)

bpy.context.area.tag_redraw()

print("Checkpoint2")
time.sleep(1)


bpy.ops.clip.detect_features()
print("Checkpoint3")
time.sleep(1)

print("Checkpoint4")
```

**Results:**

> *Checkpoint1*
>
> *Checkpoint2*
>
> *Checkpoint3*
>
> *Checkpoint4*

Frame updates and trackers appear detected from the original frame.

**Here is what I want to happen:**

Frame changes to the new frame in the timeline.

*Checkpoint1*

Frame updates in the Novie Clip Editor.

*Checkpoint2*

Detects feature on the updated frame.

*Checkpoint3*

*Checkpoint4*

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The issue you encountered with `bpy.ops.clip.detect_features()` processing the previous frame instead of the frame you set in `bpy.context.scene.frame_current` is due to the order in which operations are executed in Blender's event loop.

When you set `bpy.context.scene.frame_current` with a frame value, it updates the current frame value in the scene, but it doesn't immediately update the interface. The interface update occurs during the event loop, and `bpy.ops.clip.detect_features()` may execute before the interface update happens.

To work around this issue, you can use a timer event to delay the execution of `detect_features()` and make sure it happens after the frame update using the [`bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.app.handlers.html#bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post) application handler. Also a side note, you always need to make sure you execute `ops` functions in the correct context. The `bpy.ops.clip.detect_features()` function needs to be executed in the *CLIP_EDITOR* context. Read more about [context overrides here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6101/poll-failed-context-incorrect-example-bpy-ops-view3d-background-image-add)

```
import bpy

frame_to_detect_features = 130 # change to MiddleFrame in your case

def detect_features_callback(scene):
    area_type = 'CLIP_EDITOR'
    areas = [area for area in bpy.context.window.screen.areas if area.type == area_type]

    if len(areas) <= 0:
        raise Exception(f"Make sure an Area of type {area_type} is open or visible on your screen!")

    with bpy.context.temp_override(
        area=areas[0],
    ):
        bpy.ops.clip.detect_features()

    bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.clear()

bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.clear()
bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.append(detect_features_callback)

bpy.context.scene.frame_set(frame_to_detect_features)
```

Make sure both the *Movie Clip Editor* area and *Script Editor* area are open in the same window for this script to work. In this script, the callback function `detect_features_callback` gets invoked automatically after `bpy.context.scene.frame_set()` has finished processing. Take note we need to use `bpy.context.scene.frame_set()` instead of `bpy.context.scene.frame_current` for the callback to get invoked.